# MySQL load data based on first line

Tags: php, mysql, sql

is there way to load data from CSV file where 1st line are COLUMN names and other lines are data ?

i tryed simple query, but it insert without any ordering

Query :

```
$q = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$filepath.$filename_update."' 
    INTO TABLE ".$dbName.$tableName."_uimport_update
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
    ENCLOSED BY '\"'
    IGNORE 1 LINES;";
```

DB columns

```
product_id, product_sku, ...
```

CSV file

```
mdate, product_sku, ....
```

bad result:

```
product_id, product_sku, ...
mdate, product_sku, ....
```

wanted result:

```
product_id, product_sku, ...
product_id, product_sku, ....
```

Comment: If the first line matches the name of the columns in your database, you can scrape it and pass it into your query line. Per the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html), the syntax would be `LOAD DATA INFILE 'persondata.txt' INTO TABLE persondata
(col_name_or_user_var [, col_name_or_user_var] ...);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the order of the columns in your Query. I'd recommend to add a character set to the query aswell as an "OPTIONALLY" for the enclosure.

But let's have a look:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bar` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `baz` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bla` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

> vagrant@fancyhost:~$ cat foo.csv
>
> bar;baz;bla
>
> "test bndg";baaaaaaaaaaaaz;"yeyo"
>
> "I looooooove dummy data";debug;dummy
>
> test1;test2;test3

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/vagrant/foo.csv' INTO TABLE foo CHARACTER SET utf8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' IGNORE 1 LINES (bar,baz,bla)
    -> ;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 3  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM foo;
+----+-------------------------+----------------+-------+
| id | bar                     | baz            | bla   |
+----+-------------------------+----------------+-------+
|  1 | test bndg               | baaaaaaaaaaaaz | yeyo  |
|  2 | I looooooove dummy data | debug          | dummy |
|  3 | test1                   | test2          | test3 |
+----+-------------------------+----------------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/vagrant/foo.csv' INTO TABLE foo CHARACTER SET utf8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' IGNORE 1 LINES (bar,bla,baz)
    -> ;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 3  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM foo;
+----+-------------------------+----------------+----------------+
| id | bar                     | baz            | bla            |
+----+-------------------------+----------------+----------------+
|  1 | test bndg               | baaaaaaaaaaaaz | yeyo           |
|  2 | I looooooove dummy data | debug          | dummy          |
|  3 | test1                   | test2          | test3          |
|  4 | test bndg               | yeyo           | baaaaaaaaaaaaz |
|  5 | I looooooove dummy data | dummy          | debug          |
|  6 | test1                   | test3          | test2          |
+----+-------------------------+----------------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can change the order easily according to your example :)